# Поиск по id Reddit API

Tags: api

Как по API получить конкретный пост используя его ID?
Я запрашиваю так: `https://www.reddit.com/r/cats.json`
Теперь мне нужно получить только один пост основываясь на его id, либо используя что-то другое

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По этой ссылочке выдается вся инфа по посту

```
https://www.reddit.com/api/info.json?id=*NAME*
```